# Mysql, insert to an ordered list

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize my database query time. I have a list of items, each item has a property (or attribute if you prefer) that I use to index the item, for e.g, object is an image file name, and the index is the timestamp the image was taken. I want to keep the list of file names sorted ascending by timestamp so that when I query, I don't need a SORT BY. (There is chance that the later-inserted one has lower timestamp).

1. Is there any way in MySQL to achieve that?
2. Is it faster than just use SORT BY when retrieving?

Tks

Comment: How big are your datasets.  To be honest, any performance gained from optimising the ordering is going to be miniscule unless you are dealing massive data.

Comment: About millions of image files, that's our target, seriously.

Comment: Absent an `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL makes no guarantees over the order in which results will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any way in MySQL to achieve that?*

There is no way to insert new record into middle of the table. And the main, as @eggyal said in his comment - there is no guarantees that records will be returned in the order which they were inserted; you need to use ORDER BY clause.

*Is it faster than just use SORT BY when retrieving?*

It not faster, but it is the way. Use indexes you need.